# How to understand the result of the "ros2 topic info /camera/color/image_raw" is 0

Tags: ros, ros2, ament, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I launch `realsense_ros2_camera` ,I use `ros2 topic info /camera/color/image_raw` to print information about the /camera/color/image_raw topic,the result is :

```
Topic: /camera/color/image_raw
Publisher count: 0
Subscriber count: 0
```

In subscriber,it can't auto call the callback function.I want to know if it is because there is no publisher lead to can't auto call the callback function.

To be honest,I don't understand that there is no publisher why does the topic exist.

Thanks very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295902/how-to-understand-the-result-of-the-%22ros2-topic-info-/camera/color/image_raw%22-is-0/) by [RachelRen](https://answers.ros.org/users/35425/rachelren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears you have no one subscribed to the topic- do you have another application which is actively using that information? rostopic tools won't count themselves as sub/pubs.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RachelRen](https://answers.ros.org/users/35425/rachelren/) on 2018-07-02**:
I writed a subscriber for it.When I launched the subscriber,the subscriber count is 1,but the callback function not executed.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-07-04**:
The callback will be executed when messages are received on that topic.
If you publish to that topic (e.g. with `ros2 topic pub /camera/color/image_raw sensor_msgs/Image`) the callback should be called.

The issue seems to be that the launched realsense node doesn't publish any message on the topic

**Comment by [RachelRen](https://answers.ros.org/users/35425/rachelren/) on 2018-07-04**:
@marguedas Thanks for you explanation,I understand why the callback is not called.

Thanks everyone.